# Rails Rspec warning: "This dynamic method is deprecated."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

My Rails 4/Ruby 2 app is throwing the following warning every time my RSpec tests create a FactoryGirl object: "DEPRECATION WARNING: This dynamic method is deprecated. Please use e.g. Post.find_or_create_by(name: 'foo') instead."

This warning is not thrown when I run my app in development. Is FactoryGirl's code throwing this? I tried to find some information but it doesn't look like other people are getting this.

Comment: What version of FactoryGirl are you running?

Answer (score 1):

If you tell Rails to give you a full stack trace for the deprecation warning, you should be able to diagnose it pretty easily. The warnings are coming from a library called `ActiveSupport::Deprecation` - tell it to run in debug mode.

```
# config/environments/test.rb
ActiveSupport::Deprecation.debug = true
```

For me, the warnings were caused by an old version of the [Stringex](https://github.com/rsl/stringex) library.

FactoryGirl would make a new model, which would trigger a call to one of the Stringex methods, which would raise the warning, although there was no way to see that until I turned on full stack traces. `bundle update stringex` solved the issue with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's coming from [`ActiveRecord`](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders/blob/f6ed71d62d47f0f6397b5b3e801271567f30f960/lib/active_record/deprecated_finders/dynamic_matchers.rb).

```
module DeprecationWarning
  def body
    "#{deprecation_warning}\n#{super}"
  end

  def deprecation_warning
    %{ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn("This dynamic method is deprecated. Please use e.g. #{deprecation_alternative} instead.")}
  end
end
```

I'm not sure why you're not getting the warnings in development. Is your environment suppressing the warnings?

Comment: No, deprecatin warnings are not silenced. What is the dynamic method being referred to?

Comment: The deprecation is referring to a method of the form `Post.find_or_create_by_name('foo')` which is deprecated in Rails 4 that is being called somewhere by FactoryGirl it seems. Are you using `factory_girl_rails` in your Gemfile, or just `factory_girl`?

Comment: I'm getting this warning while using Rolify 3.2.0 which calls:
    role.class.find_or_create_by_name_and_resource_type_and_resource_id(role_name, resource_type, resource_id)